# Code blocks runing error: Build failed

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, and now learning it using code blocks (version: codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe). My test codes are as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0, val = 1;
    // keep executing the until val is greater than 10

    while (val <=10 ) {
        sum += val; // short-cut assignment
        ++val; // add 1 to val
    }
    std::cout << "Sum of 1 to 10 inclusive is "
              << sum << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

These codes are written in an empty file named ex1.cpp. Then I tested by click "Build and run". As a result, another file main.cpp (I did not write this) pops up:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Screenshot attached for your better checking:

[image]

Comment: That is a `.c` file which is C, not C++. You need to change it to a `.cpp` file. Two different languages.

Comment: You are right. But when I corrected this problem, these codes still cannot be run successfully. I attached a new figure for your reference.

Comment: Also make sure that you have created a c++ project in Code::Blocks, so that it uses the correct compiler.

Comment: why did you delete the first line `#include <iostream>`? you need that to import the standard input and output functions

Comment: @gurka  I did create a C++ project, but when I created an empty file and saved it, it turned into a c file for some reason

Comment: You still need to include `<iostream>`. Also, please post the error messages themselves, rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @m_callens I added that, but the "system' error can not be addressed. do I need do some declaration for it?

Comment: @jingweimo Try `#include <cstdlib>`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Comment: add `#include <cstdlib>` after `iostream` for your system call

Comment: also the preferred method of pausing the console is using `cin.get()` which prompts the user for an empty line of input and therefore pauses until something is pressed.

Comment: CodeBlocks seems to generate a `main.cpp` file when you create a project. Just delete it.

Comment: @jingweimo :You said you are using code blocks 16.01 .Then could you please try this for me. Goto `File->New Project->Consule Application->c++>(Type name for project)->next->finish`.After that click the + sign and double click main.cpp ,then replace all the code you see with your test code and try **build and run**

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error is because your compiler settings is not correct.You need to make sure that you use GNU GCC MinGW Compailer.Go To Settings-->Compiler and make sure every thing is same as on the screen shot.[image]

Solving common codeblocks problems :[Link](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Common_problems_and_solutions)

Comment: The changes to the code you made are obsolesce. And try to refrain from answering questions that can be resolved by simple comments such as this.

Comment: No, no, no, no, ten more times no. No including C headers instead of C++ headers (`<cstdlib>`), and no damned `using namespace std;` to screw up the global namespace.

Comment: I thought every question should have an answer rather than comment. Since the purpose of this site is to make a library of question and answers. PS :I unlocked commenting 10 minutes before.I will try commenting from next time onwards

Comment: I think I used a correct complier since I download the code blocks version with the complier ( codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe)

Comment: @m_callens: wait, why? You shouldn't answer in comments, you should answer in answers. I think what Aravind did is right. There are users that keep inviting people to refrain from answering in comments, and I think they are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

I really did something wrong about coding:

when I create an empty file in the project, it will result in two main functions in the that project one of which is that "hello world" file automatically generated, which is not allowed by C++.

To build it successfully, what I did is to overwrite the codes in the main.cpp.